How to save emails sent with Noticed gem
I need to save all sent emails to database. The usual way I would do it would be to add a custom delivery job to ApplicationMailer and handle it in that job (I got the idea from https://engineering.monstar-lab.com/en/post/2022/10/05/Handling-bounced-emails-by-SES-with-Rails/).
So my application_mailer.rb looks like this:
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  self.delivery_job = ::Jobs::EmailDeliveryJob
  # ...
end

And the email_delivery_job.rb:
module Jobs
  class EmailDeliveryJob < ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob

    queue_as :email_sending

    def perform(mailer, mail_method, delivery_method, args:, kwargs: nil, params: nil)
      response = super # Call the parent ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob `perform` method to send the email

      # Store the record inside SentEmails
      user = params[:user]

      return if user.blank?

      SentEmail.create!(
        user:,
        email_type: "#{mailer}.#{mail_method}",
        subject: response.subject,
        sent_at: Time.zone.now,
        content: response.body.to_s
      )
    end

  end
end

It works fine when I call the mailer methods myself, but when an email is sent via Noticed (deliver_by :email, mailer: 'SomeMailer', method: :mail_type, format_data: :some_data, delay: 1.second) it skips the MailDeliveryJob.
I need to get the subject and body data from the email that is being sent by Noticed (at least), but I don't know how. Ive tried extending the deliver method from the Noticed::Base (we're using v1) but there is no useful data available at that point in the execution.
Any ideas?

I have solution with gem https://github.com/kortirso/emailbutler
It works on mailer level, so does not matter how to send emails
Process of monitoring is simple
include Emailbutler::Mailers::Helpers to any mailer where you need track emails
helper has
included do
  after_action :save_emailbutler_message
end

private

def process_action(*args)
  build_emailbutler_message(args)

  super # actual sending of email
end

def build_emailbutler_message(args)
  @emailbutler_message = Emailbutler.build_message(
    mailer: self.class.to_s,
    action: action_name,
    params: serialize({ mailer_params: params, action_params: args[1..] }, false)
  )
end

def save_emailbutler_message
  message.message_id = @emailbutler_message.uuid
  Emailbutler.set_message_attribute(@emailbutler_message, :send_to, message.to)
  Emailbutler.save_message(@emailbutler_message)
end

So with build_emailbutler_message and save_emailbutler_message you can save any params of mailer to database
In addition there is controller for receiving webhooks and confirming email deliveries, and re-send emails by saved params
